# Is there a way to pivot a field using list instead of an aggregate in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm really sorry if this question is a duplicate, but my google fu failed me and I could not find an answer to my problem.

I would like to pivot my data by a list, not an aggregate. I can't really put it into words (sorry but english is not my native language), so let me show you all an example.

I have my data in the following structure:

```
Project | Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)
A       | 15/jan/21
B       | 20/jan/21
C       | 31/jan/21
D       | 15/feb/21
E       | 22/feb/21
F       | 01/mar/21
G       | 10/mar/21
H       | 27/mar/21
I       | 30/mar/21
```

Using an Excel pivot table it's easy to get this kind of summarization:

```
        |      2021       |
        | jan | feb | mar |
Project |  3  |  2  |  4  |
```

Now what I really want is a list like the following, that I can't get from a pivot table even if my life was on the line:

```
| jan | feb | mar |
|  A  |  D  |  F  |
|  B  |  E  |  G  |
|  C  |     |  H  |
|     |     |  I  |
```

I can get there by using a combination of the INDEX, ROW, COL and MATCH functions in a spreadsheet, but I get the feeling there's an easier way out there that I'm too stupid to see.

Can anyone please show my this better way, or point me to some documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution to this using just one Pivot Table (Pivot tables are designed to aggregate values in a matrix of two axes, which is not task here). However, you could get the same result by using one PivotTable per month next to eachother, which could work if the distinct months in the dataset are somewhat predictable- but I admit that's not a neat solution.

An alternative approach that doesn't provide the exact same result, but may serve as a next best option is to put Project on rows and in values (Count), and Month (Due Date) on columns for this result:

[Alternative solution - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdJuw.png)

[Alternative solution - structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2bIv.png)

Even though it is not what you are asking, I think it's worth mentioning that transforming the table with Power Query instead of a Pivot Table might be a better approach

EDIT:
Here's a Power query solution that does the trick for you.
Create a table and make sure its named "Table1", or edit that reference in the code. The table structure is identical to your example in the OP.

[Here's the result I got from PQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA2WN.png) (Don't mind the header language)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project ", type text}, {" Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)", type datetime}}),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([#" Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)"]), type text),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Inserted Month Name",{{" Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{" Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Month Name"}, {{"Data", each _, type table [#"Project "=text, #" Due Date (dd/mmm/aa)"=datetime, Month Name=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Data], "Index", 1, 1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Data"}),
    #"Expanded Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", {"Project ", "Index"}, {"Project ", "Index.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Index", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Index"[#"Month Name"]), "Month Name", "Project "),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column1",{"Index.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns2", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns2"[#"Month Name"]), "Month Name", "Project ")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for the contribution! I guess something went wrong when you uploaded the images, as both links point to the same image.
I'm open to trying the Power Query approach, but could not make it work. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the correct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdJuw.png

You can even add functions next to the pivot table replacing 1 with the project ID, but you would be left with gaps so long as other projects with other due months are present. IF(B3=1;A3;"") or something like that.

Comment: About Power Query - I don't have the approach on the top of my head. I would have to try and fail, so I'm sorry that I can't give you a more clear answer right now. That or VBA, but thats a topic I don't have the necessary expertise to provide useful help.

Comment: VBA is another way of doing it, certainly, but I was looking for something way simpler than that.
I'm hitting a dead end on the Power Query approach, as I can aggregate and get the count of projects by month, but if I choose Don't aggregate on the advanced options the table only shows one row with the value Error in all columns.

Comment: Thomas, thanks a lot!! That's exactly what I was looking for, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to having a different output format? If you create your pivot table and add to the data model, then you have the option of using the ConcatenateX DAX formula as a measure in your pivot table. Output could look like this (two options listed:)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time Isolated!
The layout I'm trying to achieve is in line with some reports that we use at my job, which are in line with the mindset of our management.
But your second option could easily be transferred to columns and then transposed to achieve my layout, so if nobody else suggests something closer, I'll mark this as an answer later!